# Fast way of generating combinations with constraints?

Tags: python, algorithm, combinatorics

I have generator function that creates a Cartesian product of lists. The real application uses more complex objects, but they can be represented by strings:

```
import itertools

s1 = ['a', 'b']
s2 = ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
s3 = ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
s4 = ['g']

p = itertools.product(*[s1,s2,s3,s4])
names = [''.join(s) for s in p]
```

In this example, the result is 32 combinations of characters:

```
names
['accg', 'acdg', 'aceg', 'acfg', 'adcg', 'addg', 'adeg', 'adfg', 'aecg',
 'aedg', 'aeeg', 'aefg', 'afcg', 'afdg', 'afeg', 'affg', 'bccg', 'bcdg',
 'bceg', 'bcfg', 'bdcg', 'bddg', 'bdeg', 'bdfg', 'becg', 'bedg', 'beeg',
 'befg', 'bfcg', 'bfdg', 'bfeg', 'bffg']
```

Now, let's say I have some constraints such that certain character combinations are illegal. For example, let's say that only strings that contain the regex '[ab].c' are allowed. ('a' or 'b' followed by any letter followed by 'c')

After applying these constraints, we are left with a reduced set of just 8 strings:

```
import re
r = re.compile('[ab].c')
filter(r.match, names)
['accg', 'adcg', 'aecg', 'afcg', 'bccg', 'bdcg', 'becg', 'bfcg']
```

In the real application the chains are longer, there could be thousands of combinations and applying the hundreds of constraints is fairly computationally intensive so I'm concerned about scalability.

Right now I'm going through every single combination and checking its validity. Does an algorithm/data structure exist that could speed up this process?

**EDIT:**
Maybe this will clarify a little: In the real application I am assembling random 2D pictures of buildings from simple basic blocks (like pillars, roof segments, windows, etc.). The constraints limit what kind of blocks (and their rotations) can be grouped together, so the resulting random image looks realistic, and not a random jumble.

A given constraint can contain many combinations of patterns. But of all those combinations, many are not valid because a different constraint would prohibit some portion of it. So in my example, one constraint would contain the full Cartesian product of characters above. And a second constraint is the '[ab].c'; this second constraint reduces the number of valid combinations of the first constraint that I need to consider.

Because these constraints are difficult to create; I looking to visualize what all the combinations of blocks in each constraint look like, but only the *valid* combinations that pass all constraints. Hence my question. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of casting the iterator to a list(), just use the iterator in your list comprehension (where p is currently).

Comment: Wouldn't `s3 = ['c']` work just as well?  That is, instead of filtering the output, how about limiting the inputs?

Comment: @BrentWashburne yes I think in this example you could set `s3 = ['c']` but in the real application there are more complex constraints in which the inputs can't be eliminated a priori. For example, what if there was a constraint that only two consecutive identical letters are allowed (e.g. 'cc', 'dd', 'ee, 'ff')

Comment: In that case, `s2 = s3 = ['c']`, then `s2 = s3 = ['d']` and so on.  My point is that you can really speed things up by being smart with the inputs instead of filtering every possible combination, knowing that many of them are unused.  If all else fails, use filters.

Answer (score 6):

Try just providing the iterator that generates the names directly to filter, like so:

```
import itertools
import re

s1 = ['a', 'b']
s2 = ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
s3 = ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
s4 = ['g']

p = itertools.product(*[s1,s2,s3,s4])
r = re.compile('[ab].c')
l = filter(r.search, (''.join(s) for s in p))
print(list(l))
```

That way, it shouldn't assemble the full set of combinations in memory, it will only keep the ones that fit the criteria. There is probably another way as well.

**EDIT:**

One of the primary differences from the original, is that instead of:

```
[''.join(s) for s in p]
```

Which is a list comprehension, we use:

```
(''.join(s) for s in p)
```

Which is a generator.

The important difference here is that a list comprehension creates a list using the designated criteria and generator, while only providing the generator allows the filter to generate values *as needed*. The important mechanism is [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation), which really just boils down to only evaluating expressions as their values become necessary.

Comment: Nice. But you should use `re.search` instead of `re.match`; after all, the strings do not have to _start_ with that regex (they just do so by chance in the example), but just to contain it.

Comment: Got it, this makes sense. But is it really lazy evaluation? Every combination still has to be generated inside the filter doesn't it? That's the situation I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Yes, it is lazy evaluation because the actual list elements are generated only when they are ready to be used (which is when they are tested against the regex). I'm not sure what your exact use case is, so this is as good as it gets unless you have a better way to limit the number of combinations being generated in the first place, such as by limiting the input.

Answer (score 1):

By switching from a list to a generator, Rob's answer saves space but not time (at least, not asymptotically). You've asked a very broad question about how to enumerate all solutions to what is essentially a [constraint satisfaction problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem). The big wins are going to come from enforcing [local consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_consistency), but it's difficult to give you advice without specific knowledge of your constraints.

Comment: Thanks for the informative links! I edited my question to add more detail if that helps.